# Advanced custom fields Options page + WPML changes both languages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, wpml

I’m trying to implement WPML in a website to translate ACF’s Options Page, but whenever I update a field in the Options Page, it updates both the default WPML’s language and the English one.

I have both Custom Fields setup with WPML, i can change all the labels and when I change the language it works, but the value always stays the same for both languages.

It works everywhere outside Options Page as far as I’ve tested.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only resolve the problem by upgrading to ACF Pro, I'm not sure if ACF has support for WPML in its free version, but it worked really well wit no problems after upgrading!

Comment: So you were able to use ACF options page and translate options pages via WPML also? Same as posts/pages etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you've set the field to translatable inside the WPML options, for it to recognise the changes in the field between languages. 
Go to WPML -> Translation Management -> Multilingual Content Setup (Tab) -> Custom fields translation, and then find you field-slug.

There are three options for each field-slug.

- Don't translate.
- Copy from original to translation
- Translate

The setting should be set to *Translate*, and you will now be able translate it. I've just tested it on a site in development, where we needed to translate fields on the Options Pages as well.

Comment: I could only resolve the problem using ACF Pro, I think there's no support for WPML with ACF free version :(